# One comment per user email per post

Tags: posts, comments, email

i have this code to limit the comments per user.

```
<!-- #only one comment -->
<?php global $current_user,$post;
$args = array('user_id' => $current_user->ID,'post_id' => $post->ID);
$usercomment = get_comments($args);
if(count($usercomment) >= 1){
    echo 'Thank you for your comment';
} else {
    comment_form();
} ?>
```

My question is: how can edit this code to check for the author email rather than user id

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, the code below will generate every comment by the `$current_user->user_email` for the author_email, if the `$usercomment` return something, then there is a comment by the current user so echo "thank you", but if it's not return anything output the form.

```
global $current_user,$post;

$usercomment = get_comments(array('author_email' => $current_user->user_email, 'post_id' => $post->ID));

if($usercomment) {
    echo "Thank You";
}
else {
    comment_form();
}
```

Comment: And how can i use both? to check for author email and user id...

Comment: in the get_comments( $args ), you can view which argument is available in here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments so if you want to check both author_email and user_id you can parse an array( 'author_email' => $current_user->user_email, 'user_id' => $current_user->ID)

Comment: i did this but it didn't work: array('author_email' => $current_user->user_email,'user_id' => $current_user->ID,'post_id' => $post->ID)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to make a second query to get comments. You should be able to check the existing `$comments` object for the user email, and switch accordingly.

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$showform = true;
// var_dump($comments);
// var_dump($current_user);
if (!empty($comments) && isset($current_user)) {
  foreach ($comments as $c) {
    if ($c->comment_author_email === $current_user->data->user_email) {
      $showform = false;
      break;
    }
  }
}
if(!$showform){
    echo 'Thank you for your comment';
} else {
    comment_form();
}
```

Of course, this only works for logged-in users, but I don't know how else you could organize it. If the user is not logged-in the software doesn't know what the `user_email` will be.