# Hide review form if user has left a comment

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, comments, comment-form

I am trying to hide the comments form if a user has left a comment on that particular post, otherwise display the comment form.

I added a code snippet to a hook which hides the form, but reverts to the WordPress comment form. I'm unable to figure out how to hide that form! I would also be open to hiding that entire column if need be.

Thanks to @squints for [his post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/246668/use-hooks-to-limit-one-comment-per-user-per-post-hide-form-if-already-commente)

```
function hide_review_form( $review_form ) {
    global $current_user, $post;

$usercomment = get_comments(array('user_id' => $current_user->ID,'post_id' => $post->ID) ); 

if (! $usercomment) {
  return $review_form;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_review_comment_form_args', 'hide_review_form' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do a simple If statement like this? ...

```
if ( count( $usercomment ) < 1 ) {
    comment_form();
};
```

I don't know why you would have to unset it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Sadly changing the snippet to this did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Try below code which is return comment count of current user who posted comments on post. `get_comment()` have `count` parameter which returns only count of comment.  in your code you are using $commentdata variable which is not defined. I have tested below code and it is working fine for me. let me know if this works for you.

```
global $current_user, $post;

if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    comment_form();
} else {

      $is_commented_count = get_comments(array('user_id' => $current_user->ID, 'post_id'=>$post->ID,'count' => true) );
      if($is_commented_count < 1) {
          comment_form();
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. Unfortunately it did not work for me. I'm getting close but still not quite there. (see updated answer)